# What the webpack is complaining about?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Cypress for e2e testing.
Within Gitlab CI I'm getting this error from the webpack:

```
Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:
  cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes/test.js
The error was:
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes/test.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tape' in '/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes'
resolve 'tape' in '/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/randombytes/node_modules]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/node_modules]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/node_modules]
[/e2e/cypress/node_modules]
[/e2e/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/package.json]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape.js]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape.json]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape/package.json]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape.jsx]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape.mjs]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape.js]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/randomstring/node_modules/tape.coffee]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape.json]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape.jsx]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape.mjs]
[/e2e/cypress/integration/node_modules/tape.coffee]
```

the output speaks about not being able to resolve 'tape' in the `randomstring` package.

What can I do about this ? This is a compilation error.